# define log4j file location at runtime

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, localhost

i want to define the location of log4j to be the ${catalina.base}/logs/mylog/logdate.log

but i want to do it at runtime

this is my code for defining the fileappender at runtime
if i run this offline, i get a new folder in the project and all the log goes there, which is great
but when i run the project on the server, i can't find the log.......

how do i define the location of the log at runtime  on a localhost ?

```
String targetLog = "${catalina.base}/logs/ElectronicArena/ea.log";

ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); // create appender
// configure the appender
String PATTERN = "%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n";
console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN));
console.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
console.activateOptions();
// add appender to any Logger (here is root)
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);
FileAppender appender = null;
try {
    appender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(
            "%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"), targetLog, true);
    appender.setName(TAG);
    appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
    appender.setFile(targetLog);
    appender.setAppend(true);
    appender.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
    appender.activateOptions();
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**
for some reason declaratively doesnt work:
this is my properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Console
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t](%c:%L) - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Log

log4j.appender.Log=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Log.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.Log = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.additivity = false
log4j.appender.Log.File=${catalina.base}/logs/ElectronicArena/ea.log
log4j.appender.Log.MaxFileSize = 5MB
log4j.appender.Log.MaxBackupIndex = 20
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.Log.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t](%c:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: I am curious why you want to do this programmaticaly instead of declaratively.

Comment: for some reason declaratively doesnt work - i get the console output but not the actual file that i want to have sent by email afterwards by the app

Comment: There are good reasons why the declarative is preferable -- I would strongly recommend figuring out why it does not work from a config file. Are the rest of configurations taking affect?

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with my declarative file ?

Comment: I am not expert on log4j configuration, though it looks ok to me. You should post a separate question for that. One suggestion I have is to use `-Dlog4j.debug` and maybe `-Dlog4j.configuration`. See this [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_under_Tomcat) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
String targetLog = "${catalina.base}/logs/ElectronicArena/ea.log";
```

By this one:

```
String targetLog = System.getProperty("catalina.base")  + "/logs/ElectronicArena/ea.log";
```

Comment: i tried that, the path comes back as  null/logs/ElectronicArena/ea.log